# PHP response is not being sent back by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to get values from database using AJAX when the window load event occurs. When I visit the PHP script I get the right values on screen but when I try to get it by AJAX back at another page where it supposed to be, I get only the HTML but not the PHP values. Please help me. I am so frustrated trying to solve this since yesterday!

here is my ajax script :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getReplies() {
        var commentDiv = document.getElementById("reply_comment");
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', "widgets/board_reply_fetch.php?comment_id=<?php echo $board_comment_id_number;?>", true);
        // when we make POST request, we must add this first line
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                var result = xhr.responseText;
                //result2 = result.split('/');
                console.log('Result: ' + result);
                commentDiv.innerHTML = result;
            }
        };
        xhr.send("comment_id=<?php echo $board_comment_id_number;?>");
    }

    window.addEventListener("load", getReplies);
    </script>
```

and here is my php script :

```
<?php 
require_once '../includes/session.php';
require_once '../includes/functions.php';
require_once '../includes/validation_functions.php';


$comment_id = isset($_GET['comment_id']) ? (int)$_GET['comment_id'] : '';

$reply_data = find_board_replies_by_comment_id($comment_id);

$reply_assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($reply_data);
$reply_comment_id = $reply_assoc['comment_id'];
$reply_board_id = $reply_assoc['board_id'];
$reply_user_id = $reply_assoc['user_id'];
$reply_text = $reply_assoc['reply'];
$reply_timestamp = $reply_assoc['reply_timestamp'];

$reply_user_data = find_user_data_by_id($reply_user_id);


$profile_image = $reply_user_data['profile_picture']; 
$profile_image_thumb = "uploaded_pictures/profile/$reply_user_id/" . $reply_user_id . "small.png";

if ($profile_image == "") {
    if ($reply_user_data['gender'] == "Male"){
        $user_profile_picture = "images/ProfilePicMale.png";
    } else {
        $user_profile_picture = "images/ProfilePicFemale.png";
    }
} else {
    $user_profile_picture = $profile_image_thumb;
}

$full_name = ucfirst(htmlentities($reply_user_data['first_name'])) . " " . ucfirst(htmlentities($reply_user_data['last_name']));
$time_of_post = time_of_post($reply_timestamp);
$the_reply_text = nl2br($reply_text);

?>  

<div class="reply_comment_div">
<a href="profile.php?user_id=<?php echo $reply_user_id;?>" class="board_comments_div_picture">
<img src="<?php echo $user_profile_picture;?>" width="50px" height="50px" /></a>
<a href="profile.php?user_id=<?php echo $reply_user_id;?>" class="board_comments_reply_link"><?php echo $full_name;?></a>

    <a href="edit_comment_board.php?comment_id=<?php echo $reply_comment_id;?>" class="edit_comment_button_board">Edit</a>
    <a href="widgets/delete_board_comment.php?board_id=<?php echo $reply_board_id;?>&comment_id=<?php echo$reply_comment_id;?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this admin?')" class="delete_button_status">Delete</a>

<div class="board_comment_submited_on">submitted <?php echo $time_of_post;?></div>
<span class="comment_content_span"><?php echo $the_reply_text;?></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Any message in the console?

Comment: I get the html only but even no php values

"Result:  
<div class="reply_comment_div">
...

Answer (score 0):

I can see couple of problems here:

- With POST request, you don't have to pass query string parameters. You should pass them in request body instead. So remove query string in `xhr.open`
- After sending a POST request, you are trying to access payload via `$_GET` which is meant for fetching query string parameters in `GET` request. You should use `$_POST` instead.

Modifying these two should make things work.

Having said that, I would suggest that you use GET request. Since database state is not being changed (no create or update operation is performed), GET request is makes more sense.

Comment: thank you Ritesh for the reply, well i tried what you suggested and still doesn't work :/
I tried both POST and GET to but nothing still getting the same value in the console the html without the php variables

Comment: While making XHR, what do you see in Network panel of browser?

How do you execute the PHP script in isolation?

Put `var_dump($comment_id)` to see if PHP reads comment ID from XHR.

Comment: i see the response in the console which is the html but without the php values that must be there ! so for example this : <a href="profile.php?user_id=" class="board_comments_div_picture">
 with user_id empty :/

Comment: ok i used var_dump($comment_id) and pasted the php script link, it is giving me this : string(0) ""

Comment: Similarly, use `var_dump` to inspect next variable like `reply_user_data`. We can find the culprit this way. This is old fashion way of debugging.

Comment: What about `$reply_data`? Looks like there is an issue with database query. PHP is unable to get data from database.

Comment: i var_dump($reply_data) and got this : 
object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(6) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["type"]=> int(0) }

Comment: i think the problem is in the sending the GET $comment_id
so in these lines :
xhr.send("comment_id=<?php echo $board_comment_id_number;?>");

$comment_id = isset($_GET['comment_id']) ? (int)$_GET['comment_id'] : '';

Comment: ok i found that the comment_id being passed is 13 but there is no replies for comment_id 13 so the right Id is not being passed :/

Comment: I doubted the same. That's why I asked you to have a look at the network tab in browser's developer toolbar. But you said that your PHP script is able to access `comment_id` in the request lifecycle.

Comment: so i made a test instead of entering php variable in the xhr.send i entered a number which is 16 id of a comment but i still received no data and tried both POST and GET

Comment: Do you get appropriate value in `$reply_user_data` variable for this hard-coded comment id?

Comment: ok now it worked which means no problem in the php script, i had to change a couple of things. First i did a POST request then i added this line : xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); then I placed the number 16 and now it worked i got back the reply data, but when i place the php variable echo $board_comment_id_number i dont get values

Comment: ok now we know that the problem is this : <?php echo $board_comment_id_number;?>
which i assume is in the if else statements that comes before the script, the $board_comment_id_number is way above in the page script in which i want the ajax to execute but me i placed the <script></script> in the bottom of the page

Comment: The variable `$board_comment_id_number` should be set at server side before script tag is rendered. You are generating URL dynamically at server side for AJAX. Then sending that as HTML to browser. Then the browser makes AJAX call on the URL that you initially set. So please see that the above variable has value when the page is rendered. A `var_dump` will help.

Comment: yes well i found the problem, this `$board_comment_id_number` is inside a while() loop which echo all the comments to a post, so I am using this variable outside the while loop which is giving me an empty `$board_comment_id_number` so what should i do here ? do i have to place the ajax script inside the while() loop ? but this will make it execute everytime the while loop runs :/

Comment: **I think what i must do is echo this variable in the html id attribute then read the attribute value with javascript and get the value this way But the problem is how to get the attribute value of each comment that is posted for which i want to get the replies**

Comment: To make it generic, you can store the `$board_comment_id_number` for each comment in HTML5 custom data attribute. While making AJAX call, you can read the value of these attribute by DOM traversal and construct appropriate URL on-the-fly. This will ensure code re-usability and modularity.

Comment: well i don't know how to do that, I don't know html5 so have no idea about its features :/ so i am looking to do it the classic javascript way

Comment: You want to fetch replies against each comment. Based on your architecture, you will have to make `n` AJAX calls if there are `n` comments. Variables in these calls are `comment_id` and comment DIV where response HTML will be inserted.

Comment: thanks for your help Ritesh, I managed to solve this, what i did is echo the reply_id as an attribute id value, then click the show replies and get all the replies after fetching the id value from the DOM